# About Abelian Finite Groups and Euler's Function

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group or $|G|=n$ and let $(\phi(n) ,n)=1$ (where $\phi(n) $ is Euler's function). Now prove $G$ is abelian.

Comment: You need to find the consequences of the condition on $\phi(n)$. What have you tried?

Comment: I read properties of euiler function in wiki pedia but I can't prove it.

Comment: If you write $n$ as a product of powers of prime numbers, you can compute $\phi(n)$. Then what does $(\phi(n),n)=1$ imply?

Comment: @ThibautDumont .yes ,I know it.if n= $(p_1)^{a_1} ...(p_n)^{a_n}$ then $\phi(n) =(p_1)^{a_1 -1} (p-1)...(p_n)^{a_n -1} (p_n-1)$.and because $ (\phi(n),n) =1$ then must for every n $a_n =1$ and so $n=p_1 p_2 ...p_n$ and now?group is cyclic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every group $G$ of order $n$ such that $(n,\phi(n))=1$ is in fact *cyclic*, hence abelian. For an elementary proof see one of the following references (the first proof is simple enough to be suitable for an elemenatry class in group theory, the author says):

Jungnickel, Dieter. On the Uniqueness of the Cyclic Group of Order $n$. Amer. Math. Monthly, Vol. 99, No. 6 (1992)

Gallian, J. A. Moulton, David. When is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ the only group of order $n$?, Elemente der Mathematik, Vol. 48 (1993).